# PHP Post Always Returns 1

Tags: php, mysql, post, get, sql-update

I'm trying to update mySQL database with PHP. I got form on index.php. I'm getting value of id from link using GET method and trying to transfer value to another page with input hidden.

When i try to read this value on another page it always returns 1.
Here is my code Index.php

```
<?php
    $usr = $_GET['id'];
    echo $usr ; 
?>
<form method="post" action="status.php">
    <input type="text" name="number"> <br>
    <input type="hidden" name="3" value="<?php echo (isset($usr)) ?  $usr : '' ?>" />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And Here is status.php

```
$hello=isset($_POST['3']);
echo $hello ;
echo "<br>";
```

It's always 1.

Comment: `isset()` returns a boolean true or false, so `$hello` will be that Boolean..... Boolean true displays as `1`, Boolean `false` doesn't display at all if you echo it

Comment: `$hello = isset($_POST['3'])? $_POST['3'] : 'no value posted';` print out the actual `POST` value not whether it is set or not.

Comment: Giray please check the answer and mark and up-vote that answer which is more correct and more descriptive to you. It will help others. Thanks.

Comment: I changed my code but this time it's not returning anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) return bool so if variable is available the $hello=1 else $hello=NULL

 
Wrtie POST as

```
if(isset($_POST['3']))
{
   $hello=$_POST['3'];
   echo $hello;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for information.I changed code but this time it's not returning anything.

Comment: try echo something in else

Comment: tried echo "Succeed"; it works well but echo $hello returns nothing.

Comment: try print_r($_POST); to check what is in $_POST

Comment: Array ( [number] => 3 [hidden] =>  ) Succeed

Comment: I think there is a something wrong with this line <input type="hidden" name="3" value="<?php echo $usr;?>"/>

Comment: can you try after change name='3' to name='three' and check what $_POST returning

Comment: i changed it to [hidden] i think i'm doing sth wrong on this line value="<?php echo $usr;?>"/>

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>" /> i've changed to this and its working now.

Answer (score 1):

You'll using `isset()` function to assign variables which should not be the case:

```
$hello = isset($_POST['3']);
```

This will return `true` if `$_POST['3']` is set.

As from the literal meaning `isset()` means variable is set. It's a `BOOL` function, which means that it can only return `true` when set and `false` when not set/ empty.

Thus, your code should be:

```
$hello = $_POST['3'];
```

More information on `isset()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php.

**Tip**: It is actually not a good idea to put the value in a hidden textbox and then get it using `$_GET`, as most people can just edit the value in their browser.

Answer (score 1):

It is always returning '1' because of:

```
$hello=isset($_POST['3']);
```

The function `isset()` returns `1` for if the value is set and `0` if it is not set. In binary `1` means "true" and `0` means "false"

Essentially, your code is saying that `$_POST['3']` exists.

**However**, there may be a bigger underling issue: `$_POST` is an `array` so using a number as your `input name` may be considered bad practice. Try using a name using letters instead like:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_user"/>
```

Comment: I changed to this <input type="hidden" name="hidden_" value="<?php echo (isset($usr)) ?  $usr : '' ?>" />  but this time it's not returning anything.It's empty.

Comment: Change this also.
$hello=isset($_POST['hidden_']);
echo $hello ;
echo "<br>";

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>" />  i've changed to this and its working now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using isset wrong.

This function, isset, is not to grab the value of something, but just to check if this something is defined.

Try this:

```
$hello=$_POST['3'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to get your post parameter in status.php is:

```
$hello = isset($_POST[3]) ? $_POST[3] : null;
echo $hello;
```